# How to Modify Policy settings using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to set **Computer Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> Windows Components >> Windows Installer >> "Allow user control over installs" to "Disabled".** How to do it using Powershell?
 I have read the blogs

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/05/14/managing-group-policy-with-powershell/ . http://microsoftplatform.blogspot.com/2011/11/looking-for-specific-gpo-setting.html. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25250

Based on the spread sheet downloaded the Policy Name is "**Allow user control over installs"** located in **msi.admx**.

If I do Get-GPO -Name "Allow user control over installs" , it says *Get-GPO : The "Allow user control over installs" GPO was not found*

I have also tried to search for the policy name in msi.admx file , the closest name I thought it could be is MSI_DisableUserInstalls , but even that also didnot work.

Could some one help me by giving an example of

1. How to set Allow user control over installs to Disable?
2. What's the easiest way to find the Guid for the Policy?

Note: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Try using `Get-GPO -All` to find this information.

Comment: Hi Jacob , I have used Get-GPO -All also , It has lasted for long time , but  how do I figure out which policy name out of all the list is not clear? Where as via user interface (gpedit.msc) it is clear.

Comment: Use something like `Get-GPO -All | ?{$_.DisplayName -like '*installs*'}`

Comment: No result. Nothing is there

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gpo?view=win10-ps) for `Get-GPO`, the cmdlet will return a list of Group Policy Objects and not settings.

Comment: I'm not saying that specific name will work... You need to figure out which GPO the actual setting is in. You can use a filter to help. After that, you can worry about setting the actual settings. I don't know how you could recursively search all the GPOs but I imagine that would be rather time consuming.

Comment: Hi @ShawnEsterman , Could you please tell how can modify the setting using power shell? Is there any way to do it? Could you please give pointers?

Comment: @user2844265 If you read the documentation for the module, there really doesn't look like you could do that with the GroupPolicy module. There only looks like there are cmdlets to set registry values. If you knew the registry value, you could set it with those GroupPolicy cmdlets, but it wouldn't be set using the admx templates which is a downside. The articles you referenced did mention some third-party modules for working with Group Policy, but I have never worked with them to know if its possible. Someone else who has more experience might have better insight.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to to all this R&D on reinventing the wheel when you can just rent (or buy) a car.

If the end result is to get the policy set differently, and this is assuming that you are authorized to modify group policy in your domain, why not just open the contravening policy and change it there.  You can get a better idea where it is being set if you dump your machines' policy via gpresult instead of RSOP as not everything is exposed in the GUI using RSOP.  Have gpresult dump all settings into a file by running:

```
GPRESULT /H SOMEFILE.HTML
```

...then just look for the setting by searching for 'Allow user control over installs' in the resulting file.  You will need to make sure you have the same admx/adml files that are in the group policy central store (this is an assumption of at least 2008R2 domain/forest level).

If you're not an admin with access to GPOs, you really should find someone who does or risk having to find another job.

One way to test the setting would be to make that same setting in local security policy using:

```
GPEDIT
```

This is assuming that you are an administrator for your organization and have the ability to make said modifications on any given machine.

That being said, you could also use the Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250) as a guide.  I don't have all the settings memorized either, which is why I reference it.  Use that to determine if you can modify your registry locally to accomplish the same thing.  Assuming that it is NOT CONFIGURED in your winning GPO, the setting could be made that way.

Simplest way, in my experience, would be to get that setting into a GPO - ESPECIALLY if it has been deemed beneficial to the organization's security posture.  Hopefully, there is some oversight and documentation requirements built in to your process.

Jeremy Moskowitz wrote a REALLY good book on group policy.

{ISBN:9780470581858}